# Spring Data Mongo : Rollback if exception occurs

Tags: spring, mongodb

I'm working on a project using Spring Data and MongoDB.
I'm wondering if there is some kind of solution to rollback when some exception (standard or custom) occurs.

I tried [this solution](https://www.cloudflight.io/tech/spring-transactional-no-rollback-1691/) but unfortunately it didn't work :

`@Transactional(rollbackFor = SomeException.class)`

For the moment I'm doing the rollback manually by saving what's already deleted and vis-versa.

NOTE: The exception may occur when contacting a foreign micro-service using http.
NOTE2 : I'm using an Exception handler, I removed it and still not working.

Comment: withTransaction driver helper should handle that.

Comment: Im sorry but I didn't get your point